# Chi square for filtered data from column

Tags: r, chi-squared

I tried googling this answer but I am at a loss.

So I have data like this:

```
PatientNum<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7)
Plastics <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,1) 
Age   <- c(19, 18, 35, 82, 45,46, 65) 
BloodLoss<-c(5,4,5,10,5,15,9)
AgeGroup<-c("Teens","Teens","30s", "80s","40s","40s","60s")

dataset <- data.frame(PatientNum, Plastics,Age, BloodLoss,AgeGroup)
```

And I'm trying to recreate some stats from an earlier paper where they had less data.  In it they would sometimes do a chi-square the way I would expect it, i.e.:

```
chisq.test(table(dataset$Plastics,dataset$AgeGroup))
```

But then in other tables they would do a chi-square comparing only the Teens from Plastics vs Non-plastics (1 and 0 in the Plastic column) against each other.  This is easy enough for me to do in an online chi-square calculator where I fill in (teens+plastics)/(teens+nonPlastic) vs (non-teen+plastics)/non-teen+nonPlastics)... but how do I do that in R?

Also, feel free to advise on if one of those statistical approaches should not be done.

Comment: Are you looking for a `dplyr`-based solution, hence the tag?

Comment: Oops, let me remove that tag.  Don't care if dplyr is involved.  I'm just so used to adding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a binary variable for whether or not the age group is teens. I like to give binary or boolean variables names like `isTeen` to keep track. So using an `ifelse` call, I just give that new column a 1 if `AgeGroup` is "Teens", and a 0 otherwise.

```r
PatientNum<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7)
Plastics <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,1) 
Age   <- c(19, 18, 35, 82, 45,46, 65) 
BloodLoss<-c(5,4,5,10,5,15,9)
AgeGroup<-c("Teens","Teens","30s", "80s","40s","40s","60s")

dataset <- data.frame(PatientNum, Plastics,Age, BloodLoss,AgeGroup)

dataset$isTeen <- ifelse(dataset$AgeGroup == "Teens", 1, 0)
dataset
#>   PatientNum Plastics Age BloodLoss AgeGroup isTeen
#> 1          1        1  19         5    Teens      1
#> 2          2        0  18         4    Teens      1
#> 3          3        1  35         5      30s      0
#> 4          4        1  82        10      80s      0
#> 5          5        0  45         5      40s      0
#> 6          6        0  46        15      40s      0
#> 7          7        1  65         9      60s      0

chisq.test(table(dataset$Plastics, dataset$isTeen))

#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  table(dataset$Plastics, dataset$isTeen)
#> X-squared = 1.438e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

Created on 2018-05-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This would definitely work thank you.  As an aside though... there's actually 40+ variables I'd have to create in this manner.  Is there any way to do it inside of the chisq.test(table())  code without creating a new variable?

Comment: Not sure about inside the `table()`, but that would be a good use-case for either the `apply` or `purrr::map` families to batch process columns